# Geb - Transitioning to new page on button click inside an iFrame

Tags: selenium, webdriver, geb

I am newbie to Geb. Sorry if my question is incorrect.

I am trying to click a button inside an iFrame of `CompaniesListPage` and trying to transition to `AddCompanyPage`.

With a regular button outside the iFrame, I am able to do a

`loginButton (to: CompaniesListPage){$("input", id:"loginButton")}` to transition from a LoginPage to CompaniesListPage on loginButton click.

However, with the button inside the iFrame, I don't know how to achieve this

On the CompaniesListPage, I tried this

```
static content={
        inner { $("#default_portal_select_company_page") 

            withFrame(inner){
                  addCompanyButton (to:AddCompanyPage) {$('input', id:'AddCompanyButton')}
            }
}
```

then I understood that my declaration of the addCompanyButton should be incorrect and all I wanted from that page was to click and go forward.

So, on the testcase, i did a

```
withFrame (inner){

    $('input', id:'AddCompanyButton').click()
}
```

this works. However, since the page has already moved to `AddCompanyPage` now and wanted to work on it, I tried `page (AddCompanyPage)`

This throws a

`geb.error.UnresolvablePropertyException: Unable to resolve AddCompanyPage as content for CompaniesListPage, or as a property on it's Navigator context`

PS : Please let me know if a trace would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, the `geb.error.UnresolvablePropertyException` is simply due to a **missing import** of the AddCompanyPage in the script. Stupid me.